# JobRunr with Spring Boot - ConverterNotFound Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jobrunr

I have a Kotlin Spring Boot application and tried to integrate the JobRunr Spring Boot Starter dependency, along with the Kotlin JobRunr Support Module. Dependencies:

```
// Jackson JSON Serialization
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.3")

// Spring Boot Version is 2.7.1 (latest)

// Jobs
implementation("org.jobrunr:jobrunr-spring-boot-starter:5.1.6")
implementation("org.jobrunr:jobrunr-kotlin-1.7-support:5.1.6")
```

I configured JobRunr like this:

```
@Configuration
class JobRunrConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun jobMapper(): JobMapper {
        return JobMapper(JacksonJsonMapper(jacksonObjectMapper()))
    }
}
```

I'm using Postgres as my database.

Application properties are as follows:

```
# JobRunr
org.jobrunr.background_job_server=true
org.jobrunr.dashboard=true
```

It is quite basic stuff after following the documentation, but when I try to start the application I get the error:

> Failed to bind properties under 'org.jobrunr.background-job-server' to
> org.jobrunr.spring.autoconfigure.JobRunrProperties$BackgroundJobServer".
> Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException:
> No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String]
> to type
> [org.jobrunr.spring.autoconfigure.JobRunrProperties$BackgroundJobServer]

I tried different object mappers and configurations, swapping out dependencies, but nothing is working. Anyone have some pointers or ideas in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails to parse the configuration below:

```
# JobRunr
org.jobrunr.background_job_server=true
org.jobrunr.dashboard=true
```

according to [the source code](https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr/blob/master/framework-support/jobrunr-spring-boot-starter/src/main/java/org/jobrunr/spring/autoconfigure/JobRunrProperties.java) the configuration should look like:

```
org.jobrunr.background-job-server.enabled=true
org.jobrunr.dashboard.enabled=true
```

Comment: Thanks so much,I have no idea how I could miss this...I think I need to get some sleep ^^